# Manipulating canvas children C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I can't find way to manipulating canvas children UI elements which been add programmatically. This is my code for add children in canvas. I want to manipulating every of those canvas children in runtime.

There are any way to do this?

```
Canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.Width = mapArea.ActualWidth;
canvas.Height = mapArea.ActualHeight;
mapArea.Children.Add(new UIElement() { Uid = "Camera" + index });

Image imageB = new Image();
{
    imageB.Width = 60;
    imageB.Source = camera;
}

mapArea.Children.Add(imageB);
Canvas.SetTop(imageB, PosX);
Canvas.SetLeft(imageB, PosY);
```

Comment: Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
            UIElementCollection collection = new UIElementCollection(canvas, null);
            UIElement element = new UIElement() { Uid = "Camera" + index };
            collection.Add(element);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what you want to do to each child.  Say you want to turn all Path objects red

```
foreach (var c in canvas.Children.OfType<Path>())
{
    c.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
}
```

Or change the width of all the images:

```
foreach (var c in canvas.Children.OfType<Image>())
{
    c.Width= 10;
}
```

Or if you know that a child of a specific type exists at a specific index you can simply do:

```
var child = (Image)canvas.Children.ElementAt(3) ;
```

Comment: For example:I want to change image in canvas child No.3.How i can set image only for canvas children No.3?

Comment: You would need to access the third element and operate on it in isolation. Try using `System.Linq` to do a `.ElementAt` to get index #2.